# Calculate average of user input using for each

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Hi Im new to java and trying to do some exercises to familiarize myself with it. I am trying to calculate the sum and average of the user input numbers using a for each or enhanced for loop. What i have done is to store the numbers in an array. Can you please check if my code is correct.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

double inputNum;
double sum= 0;
int counter;

System.out.println("How many entries would you like input");
int entry = scanner.nextInt();

for (counter = 0; counter< entry; counter++){

    double [] numbers = new double[entry]; 
    System.out.println("Please input number " + (counter +1));
    numbers[counter] = scanner.nextDouble();

    for (double x : numbers[counter]) {
        x += sum;
    }

    System.out.println("The total sum is: " + sum);
    double average = sum/entry;
    System.out.println("The total average is: " + average);
}
```

Comment: for-each not applicable to expression type  double,
 need to use array or some Iterable

Comment: I was checking to see if it was possible using the for each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the inner loop. You can add each input to the sum after you store it in the array.

In addition, you should allocate the array once outside the outer loop, and not in each iteration.

```
double [] numbers = new double[entry];
for (counter = 0; counter< entry; counter++){       
    System.out.println("Please input number " + (counter +1));
    numbers[counter] = scanner.nextDouble();
    sum+= numbers[counter];
}
System.out.println("The total sum is: " + sum);
double average = sum/entry;
System.out.println("The total average is: " + average);
```

Comment: But there is no need for an array. Just keep track of the sum.

Comment: @nmore That's also true, but perhaps there's additional code that requires the array later.

Answer (score 0):

Put the sum and average logic outside the loop. This should work:

```
double [] numbers = new double[entry]; 
for (counter = 0; counter< entry; counter++){
  System.out.println("Please input number " + (counter +1));
  numbers[counter] = scanner.nextDouble();       
  sum += numbers[counter];
}

System.out.println("The total sum is: " + sum);
double average = sum/entry;
System.out.println("The total average is: " + average);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a for-each with a scanner. Also there is no need your you to be storing anything. Just keep track of the sum.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many entries would you like input?");
int numEntries = scanner.nextInt();

double sum = 0;
for (counter = 1; counter <= numEntries; counter++) {
    System.out.println("Please input number " + counter + ": ");
    sum += scanner.nextDouble();
}
System.out.println("The total sum is: " + sum);
System.out.println("The average is: " + sum / numEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same code, with average outside the loop and the useless array removed:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

double sum = 0;

System.out.println("How many entries would you like input");
int entry = scanner.nextInt();

for (int counter = 1; counter <= entry; counter++) {
    System.out.println("Please input number " + counter);
    sum += scanner.nextDouble();
}

System.out.println("The total sum is: " + sum);
double average = sum / entry;
System.out.println("The total average is: " + average);
```